# How to create a SSL connection in Websphere

Tags: java, ssl, https, websphere

I'm trying to figure to do a easy secure connection in rad 7.5 for my application.   Don't want to install http server with openssl.  Is it possible to doing it directly in WAS?

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Application Server includes by default SSL transport chain and all the bells and whistles for that. You just have to know how to map your application properly in the administrative console when you deploy it.

I think that by default the default virtual host is not mapped to the SSL enabled transport chain. You have to create a new virtual host, which you map correctly, and then map your application to use that virtual host.

The SSL keys are by default dummy keys, which you can replace by using the administrative console (at least with 6.1+) if you wish.